# Unable to delete Gitlab project having Underscore(_)in its Project Path

Tags: git, gitlab

Currently we are unable to delete GitLab project which was placed inside a group whose path name starts with underscore (`_`). On GitLab's UI we are getting an error message of

> This project was scheduled for deletion, but failed with the following message: `ContainerRegistry::Path::InvalidRegistryPathError`

Sample project path: `_SampleGroupId/sampleProject`

Can anyone help us to resolve this error? As stated earlier we want to delete the project from GitLab.

Comment: This is a bug in GitLab. See: https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab/-/issues/27483 If you're using GitLab.com and you can't change the group path or transfer the project out to a different namespace, there might not be much you can do about this. You'll have to escalate to GitLab support. If you're using a self-managed instance, a GitLab administrator can probably delete this from the GitLab rails console.

Comment: Hello sytech , We are using Gitlab so seems need to get in touch with support team for this. Let me check with support team how things move forward

Answer (score 2):

This is a [known bug](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab/-/issues/27483) in GitLab.

Transfer your project to another namespace (which does not contain an underscore) then delete it.

If you're unable to change the path or transfer the project, for gitlab.com customers, the [only resolution is to contact support and have them delete it](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab/-/issues/27483#note_750594216) due to the bug.

If you have administrative console access on a self-managed instance, [you can use the rails console](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab/-/issues/27483#note_764732183) to fix this.

> ### Self-managed workaround (via Rails console)
>
> **WORKING AROUND THIS IS DESTRUCTIVE**. When messing with the console, always double (or more) check your work, so as to not mess things up. Otherwise, you may find yourself restoring from a backup. Actually, I'd recommend just doing a backup before this anyway, for the extra security.
>
> In the [Rails console](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/administration/operations/rails_console.html), execute the following commands, replacing <project_id> and <user_id> where appropriate:

I've re-written the code instructions slightly so they can be executed a bit easier by an admin and be parameterized with the constants at the top of the script and typed/pasted into the rails console more easily and made some annotations to understand what is going on.

First set the parameters according to your need.

```rb
PROJECT_ID=<put your project id here>
USER_NAME='root'  # change this if you want to use a different user
p=Project.find PROJECT_ID
u=User.find_by_username(USER_NAME)
```

Confirm the user and project are correct then try do delete the project normally:

```rb
ProjectDestroyWorker.new.perform(p.id, u.id, {})
```

You should see `false` returned from `.perform` (you'll see `=> false` printed in the console). Confirm that the delete error is container `ContainerRegistry::Path::InvalidRegistryPathError`

```rb
p.delete_error
# => # "ContainerRegistry::Path::InvalidRegistryPathError"
```

If you confirmed the delete error, you can proceed to perform the individual destruction of project components, excluding the container registry as well as clean things up:

```rb
service =  ::Projects::DestroyService.new(p, u)
service.send(:log_destroy_event)
service.send(:trash_relation_repositories!)
service.send(:trash_project_repositories!)
service.send(:destroy_web_hooks!)
service.send(:destroy_project_bots!)
service.send(:destroy_ci_records!)
p.destroy_dependent_associations_in_batches(exclude: [:container_repositories, :snippets])
Projects::UnlinkForkService.new(p, u).execute
p.leave_pool_repository
p.destroy!
service.system_hook_service.execute_hooks_for(p, :destroy)
u.invalidate_personal_projects_count
```

Comment: Hello marc_s ,syntech  , Thanks for your reply. We have some restrictions on changing namespace so seems getting help from gitlab support support is the only option, raised a issue with them lets see how things move forward.

Comment: Thanks everyone for the reply. We were not able to delete the repository from Gitlab. so we move latest code in same repository.