# How do I create a root repository for a subgroup?

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci, gitlab-api, gitlab-pages

When I create a group on gitlab, I can create a repo `groupname.gitlab.io` that is a root folder of the site. And I can create repos such as: `css`, `img` and so on, that are subfolders of the site. How do I do the same for a subgroup?

I have created a subgroup and a repo in it `subgroupname.gitlab.io` — this way doesn't work. Then I have changed this repo's path to `..` — two dots. And now I have problems accessing this repo and managing it at all, and I can't rename or delete it. Also, I have the same problems with the subgroup and with the parent group. Also, the main page of the site has been cached somewhere and I can't update it. Clearing the runner's cache doesn't help.

The first question is: How do I create a root repository for a subgroup?

And now: How do I remove a subgroup that has a repo with the path `..` — two dots? Or is there a way to *forcibly* delete this group?

---

I have tried the web interface and the gitlab api — the result is the same. My attempts:

- Web interface:

  ```
  https://gitlab.com/group1989/subgroup/../edit
  https://gitlab.com/group1989/subgroup/%2e%2e/edit
  ```

  These `URL`s redirect to this one, which returns a `404` status code:

  ```
  https://gitlab.com/group1989/edit
  ```
- GitLab api:

  ```
  curl --request PUT --header "PRIVATE-TOKEN: <my-token>" --url "https://gitlab.com/api/v4/groups/14681317" --data "path=qwer2"
  curl --request PUT --header "PRIVATE-TOKEN: <my-token>" --url "https://gitlab.com/api/v4/projects/32327385" --data "path=qwer2"
  ```

  These commands return the same result for the `project` and for the `group`:

  ```
  {"message":"500 Internal Server Error"}
  ```

SoapUI screenshot `GET /projects/32327385`:

[image: GET /projects/32327385]

Comment: Related gitlab issue: [Remove a subgroup that has a repo with the path `..` — two dots](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab/-/issues/349156)

Comment: I guess for a self-managed version of gitlab, the solution is to transfer such groups to a ghost user and then hard delete it. But what should I do on `gitlab.com`?

Comment: It sounds similar to [this issue](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70311018/5747944). In which case, your best bet may be to contact GitLab support for gitlab.com if you're unable to transfer/delete the project on your own. Maybe transferring to a new user or group namespace you have and deleting the group or user would work -- if you're able to transfer it in the first place.

Comment: Is there a way to create a ghost user on `gitlab.com` where such groups can be moved so that they are automatically deleted? I am able to transfer those groups to another user. But one of these groups is a site with a specific name — I don't want to lose that name. How often can a ghost robot be launched so that I can recreate this group? Is it possible to solve this problem in this way?

Answer (score 0):

The related gitlab [issue](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab/-/issues/349156) has been closed, seems like after this [bug-fix](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab/-/commit/4a70f4ef144347dc9dc98240cfc63693e2458855) — so I have deleted those consequences of the previous experiments...

### Root repository for a subgroup — subfolder in the root repository

The website contains private and public pages:

```
https://site4.gitlab.io/
https://site4.gitlab.io/ru/
...
https://site4.gitlab.io/ru/2021/12/29/article-from-private-repo.html
...
https://site4.gitlab.io/ru/2022/01/05/article-from-public-repo.html
...
https://site4.gitlab.io/index.html
https://site4.gitlab.io/ru/index.html
```

The structure of Gitlab projects consists of private and public repos:

```
site4 — group-public
├─ ...
├─ ru — subgroup-public
│  ├─ 2021 — repo-private
│  │  └─ 12 — folder
│  │     └─ 29 — folder
│  │        └─ article-from-private-repo.html — file
│  └─ 2022 — repo-public
│     └─ 01 — folder
│        └─ 05 — folder
│           └─ article-from-public-repo.html — file
├─ ...
└─ site4.gitlab.io — repo-private
   ├─ ru — folder
   │  └─ index.html — file
   └─ index.html — file
```

Comment: merry christmas and happy new year