# Gitlab pages "root" page

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-pages

I have set up a gitlab server and gitlab pages for our company internal gitlab.
The configuration was made according to [Pages domain with tls support without wildcard dns](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/administration/pages/index.html#pages-domain-with-tls-support-without-wildcard-dns).

The pages work correctly and i can access the pages over the address https://pages.example.com/group/project as expected.

I was now wondering if there is a way to define the "base" or "root" page for the whole instance. That page would then be served on the address https://pages.example.com.

Currently, when I call https://pages.example.com in my browser it redirects multiple times to https://pages.example.com///////////.

The documentation describes ways of defining group pages but I have not found a way to define a "root" page.

It could also be a redirect to another page. Similar as it is done when you call https://pages.gitlab.io

Thanks for your help!

Comment: This question may be related: https://stackoverflow.com/q/70453948/358532: looks like you can do this for a group/project, but not a subgroup.